# Using oledb after fileupload

Tags: c#, file-upload, oledbconnection

I am having a problem using the oledb engine to open an excel file after using a fileupload dialog. If I set up the file name for the oledb connection with   a fixed file name it works, but if I try to get the filename from a fileupload control i get an error External table is not in the expected format. The file is not open in another application. I have tried disposing  and closing all file content in the fileupload. My code is as follows

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //sXLConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strvirtpath + "\\Unlocked  Upload-v5.xlsx " + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
    sXLConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strvirtpath + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName + " ;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
    FileUpload1.FileContent.Flush();
    FileUpload1.FileContent.Close();
    FileUpload1.FileContent.Dispose();
    FileUpload1.Dispose();
}
OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(sXLConnStr);
xlConn.Open();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you manually open the uploaded file in Excel? Perhaps it is getting mangled somehow during upload.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using EPPlus rather than Oledb for processing Excel files. It's much more powerful and easy to use. However, it doesn't support the old .xls format, only .xlsx https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the file first and then access it using the path where it is saved.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(directory + @"\" + filename);
```

Comment: This is not working. Do you mean save it to a different directory?

Comment: This worked when saving the file to a different path